# Find $a$ and $b$ so that the function $f$ is differentiable everywhere

Tags: calculus

Find $a$ and $b$ so that the function $f$ is differentiable everywhere:

$$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
9\cos x  & \mbox{if $x<0$} \\
ax + b   & \mbox{if $x \geq0$}
\end{cases}$$

Comment: Please don't just dump undigested questions here. Give some indication of where you found the question, why it interests you, what you understand about it, what progress you have made on it, where you get stuck on it, and so on.

Answer (score 3):

Of course, the only problem is at $0$.

Compute the right and the left limit of $f$ at $0$.

Equate these with $f(0)$ to ensure continuity at $0$.

This will give you $b$.

Then compute the right and left limit of $f'$ at $0$.

Equate these to ensure differentiability at $0$.

This will give you $a$.